# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property '' of undefined

Tags: node.js

So, I'm trying to create a function that will warn a user and write it to a JSON file. However, when I try to use the command, I get an error:

> "Cannot set property '(discord user ID)' of undefined".

I have done the same code in another command and it works perfectly fine so I'm rather confused.

```
const fs = module.require("fs");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let toWarn = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
    if(!toWarn) return message.channel.send("You did not specify a user mention or ID.");

    if(toWarn.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send("You cannot mute yourself.");
    if(toWarn.highestRole.position >= message.member.highestRole.position) return message.channel.send("You cannot warn someone with an equal or higher role.");

    bot.warns[toWarn.id] = {
        guild: message.guild.id,
        reason: args
    };

    fs.writeFile("./warns.json", JSON.stringify(bot.warns, null, 4), err => {
        if(err) throw err;
        message.channel.send("I have warned the user.");
    });
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "warn"
}
```

The debug says it's an error with the bot.warns part. I am using VS Code, if that's any help. Thanks in advance, and thanks for fixing the code block.

Comment: Does property `warns` of `bot` exists before you access it?

Comment: I don't think so, but I don't remember referencing it in my other command. I'll check.

Comment: It did exist for my other command and had a code block in another file. I hadn't thought of that, thanks!

Comment: You may want to write an answer, in order to let people know how you solved this.